# Delete duplicate nodes from sorted linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

The following code snippet is to remove duplicates from sorted linked list. Please suggest me the changes that needs to be made to correct the code as getting wrong output for node values 3 3 3 4 5 5 . Expected Output is 3 4 5 and what I am getting is 3 4 5 5 .

```
static SinglyLinkedListNode removeDuplicates(SinglyLinkedListNode head) {


SinglyLinkedListNode temp,temp1;
if((head==null)||(head.next==null))
    return head;

for(temp=head;temp.next!=null;temp=temp.next)
{

    for(temp1=temp.next;temp1.next!=null;temp1=temp1.next)
    {
        if(temp.data==temp1.data)
        {
            temp.next=temp.next.next;
        }
    }
}

return head;

}
```

Comment: Your loop end conditions are off by one. You're checking that `temp.next != null` and `temp1.next != null`, which means that  neither `temp` nor `temp1` will ever be the final element in your list, which is why your final `5` isn't getting removed.

Answer (score 0):

Just 3 changes needed,

1. An extra condition to check whether we have detected duplicate elements and we have 
   reached the end of the linked list or not, based on this condition we can decide 
   whether to point temp to next node or end our linked list there.
2. Now we need to be careful with the 2nd for loop condition, as we are traversing till the end node now, we have to set the condition as temp1 != null (instead of <strike>temp1.next!=null</strike>).
3. In the top most loop also we need to set the condition as temp != null( instead of <strike>temp.next!=null</strike>). That's it.

Complete updated code:

```
static SinglyLinkedListNode removeDuplicates(SinglyLinkedListNode head) {

    SinglyLinkedListNode temp,temp1;

    if((head==null)||(head.next==null))
        return head;

    for(temp=head;temp!=null;temp=temp.next)
    {

        for(temp1=temp.next;temp1!=null;temp1=temp1.next)
        {
            if(temp.data==temp1.data)
            {
                if(temp.next.next != null){
                    temp.next=temp.next.next;
                } else {
                    temp.next = null
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return head;

}
```

Hope that helps!